# How to create SSRS Cover page without the use of sub reports

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to create a cover page in SSRS. I have created a reporting template for use within the company. This template needs to have a cover page which houses our confidentiality notice. Only one page, the first page, and at the beginning of every report.

Sub reports are not an option in this particular situation. We use Share point as our report delivery system. Promoting reports with subreports means that each report and subreport must be configured. So if my template includes a subreport as the cover page; then every report submitted will actually be two reports, (or more if they include additional subreports). Each report is an .rdl and each subreport is an .rdl, so you must promote and configure two .rdls to production. Therefore, this is not a feasible option. (Remember how Crystal Reports allowed developers to embed subreports and the embedded subreport(s) did not need configuring when promoting to production in Crystal Enterprise? Where is that in SSRS/Sharepoint?)

What options do I have to include a Cover Page with just the Report Title and company confidentiality notice, without use of a subreport, and something that can be added to my template?

(I already added a rectangle to the body, added a text box in the rectangle, and added a page break to rectangle to create a cover page, but the populated rectangle makes the template look full and busy when developing, it is in the way.)

Other Options, Advice and Work arounds are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My "advice" would be to just deploy the 2 rdls and move on. In Visual Studio you can hold down the Ctrl key and select multiple reports, then right-click and choose deploy to send them all to your server.  So the extra effort is a single extra click - seems "feasible" to me.

Crystal and SSRS were developed by different companies so ... they are different.

Comment: Hi @mike-honey, this is a not a good solution but it seems to be the only one. Who to contact at MSOFT for an improvement?

Comment: they gather feedback for SQL through here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback

Comment: Hi @mike-honey, many thanks for getting back to that questions. Your answers , Hannover's & your's sir, are good but it only gives workaround. So far, it is something that is missing with SSRS. As Hannover was first to answer, the bounty goes to him in this situation. All the best and thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

How about a text box that points to a field in a server with your header information?

Something like:

```
="<b>" & Globals!ReportName & "</b>" 
    & "<br><font size = '2'>" & First(Fields!Confidentiality.Value, "Confidentiality_Notice") & "<font>"
```

You can use HTML to format paragraphs, make line breaks and control font size. It would just be a single text box in each report. But you would have the additional overhead of the separate data source and dataset in your template.

Comment: Hi @hannover-fist, many thanks for getting back to that question. Your answers , Mike Honey's & your's sir, are good but it only gives workaround. So far, it is something that is missing with SSRS. As you were the first to answer, the bounty goes to you in this situation. All the best and thank you again.

Comment: This wouldn't be an additional report - just a single text box in a rectangle (for the page break) at the top of your project template. You could make it small and it will grow to fit all the info in your confidentiality notice.